# How to create a dynamic image gallery using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to create image gallery using Jquery, below is the image attached

[image: Image Gallery]

If you see the attached image then there is "Archive 2010" section where we have all the "Gallery Name", now if user will click on that link then that Gallery will be loaded.

And if you see the image Gallery, then there will be small image with scroller below, and if user clicks on the small Image then it will show its bigger image

Please suggest what should be the approach to implement this in my project. I know there may be lots of Jquery plugins, I need some short example, so that I can start doing.

```
1) First thing, I want that when user clicks on the "gallery name" then image gallery will be loaded with all images in the gallery.
2) Clicking on small image will show the big images
3) Clicking on the scroller small image will scroll.
```

Thanks.